# Hide or remove elments with same class inside from no child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need hide or remove, divs with same class, but one to one, actually i can delete all divs with same class in one time, and i don´t want this

The problem it´s the elements are separated not inside in container, and i think that´s the problem, but i need this sctructure, **i put my code**

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
function close_tabs(idc)
{
$(idc).parent().hide();
}
</script>
```

**CSS STYLE**

```
<style>
#elements
{
position:relative;
width:400px;
height:40px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:7px;
background-color:green;
}
</style>
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="elements" class="test_1"></div><span onclick="close_tabs(this)">Div 1</span>
<div id="elements" class="test_1"></div><span onclick="close_tabs(this)">Div 2</span>
<div id="elements" class="test_1"></div><span onclick="close_tabs(this)">Div 3</span>
<div id="elements" class="test_1"></div><span onclick="close_tabs(this)">Div 4</span>
```

I need that when click over span area, close that div and not all, but i need this works with the same html and i don´t know how do this from jquery

**Thank´s in advanced, regards**

Comment: If the user clicked the text 'Div 2,' which `<div>` should be hidden/removed? And should that `<div>` be hidden *or* removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the function to this: `prev()` get the previous sibling element, `toggle()` give elements the ability to hide and show sequentially

```js
function close_tabs(idc) {
  $(idc).prev().remove();
  $(idc).remove();
}
```

```css
#elements
{
position:relative;
width:400px;
height:40px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:7px;
background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elements" class="test_1"></div><span onclick="close_tabs(this)">Div 1</span>
<div id="elements" class="test_1"></div><span onclick="close_tabs(this)">Div 2</span>
<div id="elements" class="test_1"></div><span onclick="close_tabs(this)">Div 3</span>
<div id="elements" class="test_1"></div><span onclick="close_tabs(this)">Div 4</span>
```

Comment: I need delete also <span onclick="close_tabs(this)">Div 1</span>, when click span also need delete span in each case, thank´s a lot

Comment: Changed. Does this satisfy you?

Answer (score 0):

**To fix your code:**

- you shouldn't have more, than 1 element with the same `id` on a page, so remove `id="elements"` from your `div` elements
- in order to easily select your elements with jQuery, I recommend to use a general class, then following more-and-more specific classes, e.g. `class="test test_1"` or `class="test test_2"`
- since you're using jQuery, you don't have to use the `onclick` attribute on your `span` elements to handle click events, you can select them more easily with jQuery, so remove the `onclick="close_tabs(this)"` from your `span` elements
- in your CSS, style your elements from more general to the most specific ones, e.g. instead of styling using `#element`, use the more general class `.test` on your elements to style them

```js
// select your elements via the '.test' class
// and handle their click events
$('.test').on('click', function () {
  // store the element wrapped with jQuery
  var element = $(this);  
  
  // hide the element
  element.hide();  
  
  // hide the element next to it
  element.next().hide();
});
```

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 7px;  
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test test_1"></div><span>Div 1</span>
<div class="test test_2"></div><span>Div 2</span>
<div class="test test_3"></div><span>Div 3</span>
<div class="test test_4"></div><span>Div 4</span>
```